# how Magento validate XSD schema?

Tags: magento2, module, xml

As we all know that  Magento 2 uses `XSD` schema files to validate the contents of all module configuration files.

But at that point, I have one question in my mind. How does Magento validate `XSD` schema?

Is this validated by `w3.org` ? And, if yes, then what happens when `w3.org` server goes down ?

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Magento_Customer" setup_version="2.0.7">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Eav"/>
            <module name="Magento_Directory"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

taken [from here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp)

> Note: The namespace URI is not used by the parser to look up
>   information.
>
> The purpose of using an URI is to give the namespace a unique name.
>
> However, companies often use the namespace as a pointer to a web page
>   containing namespace information.

So I guess you are safe. If `www.w3.org` goes offline, your magento will still work.

Comment: Thank you for sharing http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp link it helps me a lot to understand this topic.

Answer (score 3):

No Magento 2 does not use w3 to validate XML over XSD schema.

The framework validates the config files when it reads the XML file.

The code is located under `Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem` in the `_readFiles` method:

```
    if ($this->validationState->isValidationRequired()) {
        $errors = [];
        if ($configMerger && !$configMerger->validate($this->_schemaFile, $errors)) {
            $message = "Invalid Document \n";
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($message . implode("\n", $errors))
            );
        }
    }
```

And the `validate` method is located in `Magento\Framework\Config\Dom` :

```
public function validate($schemaFileName, &$errors = [])
{
    if ($this->validationState->isValidationRequired()) {
        $errors = $this->validateDomDocument($this->dom, $schemaFileName, $this->errorFormat);
        return !count($errors);
    }
    return true;
}
```