# Merged Layout schema validation error in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to understand how schema validation validates merged layout files in Magento 2. XSD schema called layout_merged.xsd is used to validate layout in the `\Magento\Framework\Config\Dom::validateDomDocument()` method. It seems error occurs in `system.log` file every time it is validated.

```
[2017-02-09 10:59:34] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE2_46f1b068ec7ccf4878f9284dd1137afd1 and handles catalog_product_prices: Please correct the XML data and try again. Warning: DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): Invalid Schema in vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on line 311 [] []
```

The merged file seems correct for example `catalog_product_prices.xml`, I saved content of the merged xml into the file and added  `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_merged.xsd"` to see how it validates in PHPStorm.

It shows that `block`, `referenceContainer`, `arguments` are not allowed node names in the xml. According to `layout_merged.xsd` these nodes are allowed.

I will appreciate if you could advice me if I am missing something.

**Updated follow up information.**
Here is a one of merged layouts, let's call it "a collection of all catalog_product_prices.xml layout files":

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_merged.xsd">
<handle id="handle">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool" name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\PriceBox</item>
                <item name="default_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/default.phtml</item>
           <item name="default_amount_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount</item>
           <item name="default_amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
           <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="special_price" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/special_price.phtml</item>
              </item>
              <item name="tier_price" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/tier_prices.phtml</item>
              </item>
              <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox</item>
                 <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/final_price.phtml</item>
              </item>
              <item name="custom_option_price" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
              </item>
              <item name="configured_price" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\ConfiguredPriceBox</item>
                 <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/configured_price.phtml</item>
              </item>
           </item>
        </argument>
     </arguments>
  </block>
  <referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
     <arguments>
        <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="adjustments" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="default" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="tax" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="adjustment_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Tax\Pricing\Render\Adjustment</item>
                    <item name="adjustment_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Tax::pricing/adjustment.phtml</item>
                 </item>
              </item>
           </item>
        </argument>
        <argument name="bundle" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="adjustments" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="bundle_option" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="tax" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="adjustment_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Tax\Pricing\Render\Adjustment</item>
                    <item name="adjustment_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Tax::pricing/adjustment/bundle.phtml</item>
                 </item>
              </item>
           </item>
        </argument>
     </arguments>
  </referenceBlock>
  <referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
     <arguments>
        <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="wishlist_configured_price" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Wishlist\Pricing\Render\ConfiguredPriceBox</item>
                 <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/configured_price.phtml</item>
              </item>
           </item>
        </argument>
     </arguments>
  </referenceBlock>
</handle>
</layout>
```

I stored this layout during debug and included `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_merged.xsd">` into this file to see highlighted nodes which are not valid as per layout_merged.xsd definitions.

It shows `block`, `arguments` and `referenceBlock` as red in PHPStorm, meaning it is not valid. Here is a screenshot on how it looks like:
[image: merged layout file as a result of all catalog_product_prices.xml files]

The `vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/etc/layout_merged.xsd` file states that all mentioned nodes are allowed for use:

```
<xs:element name="handle" type="handleType">
    <xs:unique name="blockKey">
        <xs:selector xpath=".//block"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
    </xs:unique>
    <xs:unique name="containerKey">
        <xs:selector xpath=".//container"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
    </xs:unique>
    <xs:keyref name="blockReference" refer="blockKey">
        <xs:selector xpath=".//referenceBlock"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
    </xs:keyref>
    <xs:keyref name="containerReference" refer="containerKey">
        <xs:selector xpath=".//referenceContainer"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
    </xs:keyref>
</xs:element>
```

Since `layout_merged.xsd` file extends the `vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/etc/elements.xsd` it also allows using `attributes` node.

So my questions are:

1. Why result of merged layout `catalog_product_prices.xml` files highlights that nodes can't be used?
2. If all separate layout files are correct and XSD validation is passed for all individual layout files, in this example `catalog_product_pruces.xml`. why result of merged layout is failing and we see `main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: ...` records in the `system.log` file?

I assume `layout_merged.xsd` has bug it is not properly validating merged files.

Comment: Maybe that can help: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/142503/2380

Comment: THanks @RaphaelatDigitalPianism. I've read everything on the link provided. Unfortunately it does not give me a clue of a "way" how and "why" i see errors in system.log file.

Comment: Is there possibility that the merge itself produced wrong results? Are individual files valid by itself? Is this XML something yu can share?

Comment: Hi @EugeneTulika, Individual files are correct, no issues with them, merged are always failing validation. Updated my question with details.

Comment: @MaxPronko Could you help me with this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/174670/how-to-fix-please-correct-the-xml-data-and-try-again-error-in-magento-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Followed next steps:

- downloaded latest mainline from
  https://github.com/magento/magento2:develop
- created the file with the
  XML provided in the example of merged file
- added links to the schema in my IDE Everything worked well with no errors.

Then, repeated same steps, but downloaded latest for 2.1 branch of the mainline. As a result, there is the same error as it was reported.

My investigation of the issue in the git history shows that it was fixed as a part of the story on better XML validation and error processing for 2.2. A number of similar errors were fixed across other XSD files.

The issue with the 2.1 was reported back to Product Owners, backporting of the fixes from the mainline to 2.1 should be prioritized for one of the upcoming 2.1 patch releases.

Comment: Do you have a GitHub link for the issue?

Answer (score 4):

It's not 100% clear what you're asking -- but that might be because you don't have enough information to ask the right question. :)

When Magento 2.1.3 loads its layout files on a non-cached hit, after reading them from disk across every module and every theme, it ends up with a layout structure that looks like this

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <handle id="[HANDLE ID]">
        <!-- ... nodes ... -->
    </handle>
</layout>
```

This is roughly equivalent to the "Package Layout" in Magento 1.  I mentioned this briefly in my [Magento 2: 10,000 ft. Layout Rendering View](http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/139615758780/magento-2-10000-ft-layout-rendering-view) post.

The `urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_merged.xsd` schema is meant to validate these merged documents.  It's not meant to validate stand-alone documents like `catalog_product_price.xml`. If you try to run a stand-alone file through `layout_merged.xsd`, you'll get complains about

> block, referenceContainer arguments are not allowed node names in the xml

This isn't because these nodes are not allowed, it's because there's no surrounding `<handle/>` tag.  Schemas not only say what nodes are allowed, but **where** they're allowed.

It's not clear from your question if you already did this or not, but I'd jump to here

```
#File: vendor/magento//framework/Config/Dom.php
try {
    $result = $dom->schemaValidate($schema);
    if (!$result) {
        $errors = self::getXmlErrors($errorFormat);
    }
} catch (\Exception $exception) {
    libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
    throw $exception;
}
```

and log the contents of the `DomDocument` object in `$dom`.  This will be the merged XML that your system is complaining about, and the one you want to run through `layout_merged.xsd`.  If there's problems with this file, it's because something went wrong when Magento was building the handle layout file.  It's harder to be more specific than that with the information you've provided.  One possible debugging technique would be to temporarily rename all the `catalog_product_price.xml` files in the system (including Magento's) and re-add them until the error reoccurs.  (although it may be possible some PHP code is adding `catalog_product_price` handles programmatically)

Hope that helps and good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I updated my question with examples for your better understanding of a problem :). Thanks for help.